# How can I create a LINQ-to-SQL statement when I have table name as string?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

If I have the name of a database table like this:

```
string tableName = "Addresses";
string tableName = "Customers";
```

How can I construct a dynamic LINQ statement like this:

```
var items = from o in db.{tableName}
            select o;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    sb.Append(item.Id + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> results = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>
    ("SELECT contactname FROM customers WHERE city = {0}",
    "London");
```

But in this instance I don't *want* strongly typed objects as my result, I just want a recordset to pick apart.

## Answer:

Thanks Shalkalpesh, I took your advice and solved this by just **avoiding LINQ altogether**:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["main"].ToString();
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtResult);
foreach (DataRow drRow in dtResult.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(drRow["Id"].ToString());
}
da.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection here to get a handle on the right Table class.

Comment: Edward: I will suggest you to use "using" block to make sure that connection, datareader gets closed (including in the exception scenario).

Comment: If you generated your DataContext already and if you're using elsewhere els, I suggest you use DataContext.ExecuteQuery to keep things homogeneous. This method has an overload to return objects! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the recordset, you can access the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.connection.aspx) property of the `DataContext` class (`db` variable in your context) and use it to execute regular query and get the result in either of `DataTable` or `DataReader`.

Comment: Or as I said, use the ExecuteQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dynamic Linq Query library (or D-Linq for short).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I'm away from a dev machine at the moment, but would [this](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/143814.aspx) help?

It seems to suggest you should use DynamicQuery ...

> Another way - as was mentioned by
>   several commenters in my previous post
>   - is to use DynamicQuery. DynamicQuery is one of the samples installed with
>   the 101 LINQ samples and you can find
>   it by clicking on Help | Samples in
>   Visual Studio. If you drill into the
>   sample folders there's a DynamicQuery
>   sample project, which basically
>   consists of a class that provides
>   string based lambda expression
>   parsing.
>
> The class DynamicQuery class is self
>   contained and you can simply add it to
>   your project. It provides additional
>   extension methods that let you use
>   string expressions for various of the
>   query methods including the .Where()
>   method (but unfortunately for the
>   above example not the .Single()
>   method). So with Dynamic Query the
>   above .Load() method can also be
>   written as follows:

There's an actual code example on the post, too...

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL is meant to be strongly typed so I don't think you can use LINQ to SQL to use dynamic table names unless you use ExecuteQuery

Thanks

Comment: I'll add to my answer that building the expression tree would be impossible without the informations about the table being queried and I don't think there's a mechanism to dynamically fetch them according to the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Dynamic Linq is the solution here.

As far as I know, there is no solution to your problem.

Even with dynamic linq, the compiler would need to somehow figure out what table the string refers to at compile time to allow strong typing of its members.

For instance, let's say you have two tables:

```
Product {Id, Name, Value}
Customer {Id, Firstname, Surname, Address, Email, ...}
```

And you use Linq-to-SQL as your ORM:

```
var items = from p in MagicTableResolver("Product")
            where p.Firstname // <-- How could intellisense allow this?
            select p;

var items = from c in MagicTableResolver("Customer")
            where c.Name // <-- It can't, it cannot be strongly typed
            select c;
```

Comment: Right, but I just thought there would be a db.ExecuteQuery.GetUntypedDataTable() or something like that so you would have access to the tables if you need it, this is my current solution anyway to just get the connection string and bypass LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5e5f3c8-ac3a-49c7-8dd2-e248c8736ffd/using-variable-table-name-in-linq-syntax?forum=linqprojectgeneral), here's how to run some some LINQ commands on a string tablename. I haven't figured out how to get the query syntax working (like "FROM" and "SELECT"), but you can still get and insert rows.

```
Type tableType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("NameSpace.TableName");
ITable itable = dbcontext.GetTable(tableType);

//prints contents of the table
foreach (object y in itable) {
    string value = (string)y.GetType().GetProperty("ColumnName").GetValue(y, null);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

//inserting into a table
dynamic tableClass = Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
//Alternative to using tableType
dynamic tableClass = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "NameSpace.TableName").Unwrap();
tableClass.Word = userParameter;
itable.InsertOnSubmit(tableClass);
dbcontext.SubmitChanges();

//sql equivalent
dbcontext.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO [TableName]([ColumnName]) VALUES ({0})", userParameter);
```